# How avoid refresh MainActivity after returning from a second one?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

When the app is started,in onCreate of MainActivity, some loading data from sharedpreferences and some numerical computations are done. But it is not necessary doing this every time it's coming back from others activities in the app. How can I avoid this?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: How do you return to `MainActivity` from other activities? Show your code please.

Answer (score 0):

onCreate is called when a new activity is created for the first time. If you navigate to another activity and come back to previous one then onCreate will NOT be called instead onResume will be called. Have a look at the documentation explaining the lifecycle of an activity

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity